# Limit with Integral and Sigma

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

Problem: $f'(x)$ is a continuous function for $[0, 1]$. Show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n {f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)-\int_0^1f(x)dx} \right)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}$$

I tried to use the definition of the definite integral to change it to a limit but it doesn't seem to work. And I also wonder why a continuous condition for $f'(x)$ was given. I thought it might give me hints.

Can anyone give me hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

From the Trapezoidal Rule, we have

$$\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt=\frac1n \left(\frac{f(0)+f(1)}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

where we used the fact that $f'(x)$ is continuous (and therefore bounded) to assert the error term ([SEE HERE, pp.304-305](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/An_Elementary_Proof30705.pdf)).

Comment: Hmm...would $\lim_{n \to \infty} nO(1/n^{2})$ equal 0?

Comment: Yes, the error term goes to zero, which is exactly what we need to show the coveted equality.

Comment: By any chance, is it $\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{2}$? Sigma notation goes from i=1 to n so it cannot cover f(0) but it covers f(1) so...I was wondering whether the sign should be changed or not.

Comment: The upper limit on the sum is $n-1$.  So, upon subtracting from the Riemann sum, we obtain the $\frac12\left(f(1)-f(0)\right)$ term.

Comment: I think we are thinking of the same thing. I was wondering that if the sum goes from 1 to n, the sign should be minus. I agree with your edit.

Comment: Please to hear that this was helpful.  -Mark